# how can i return the name of animals that are in a List<Animals> using a List<Caretaker> specifying a caretaker java8

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

So I have a class Caretaker which holds 3 attributes

```
class Caretaker {
  private int number; // Like an ID
  private Sting name;
  private List<Animal> animals;
  // Setters & getters
}
```

and

```
class Animal {
  private String name;
  // other fields
  // Setters & getters
}
```

I want to use a stream to get a specific caretaker (is passed as an argument in the method) and return the names of the animals he/she takes care of (those are in the animal list)

```
return caretakers.stream()
                 .filter(caretaker-> caretaker.getNumber() = caretakerID)
                 .map(x->x.getAnimals()
                 .stream()
                 .forEach(z->z.getName()));
```

Comment: The `map()` is giving you a stream of lists. You want a stream of Animals. So use `flatMap()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you `filter` by ID, then map into `List<List<Animal>>`, then flatten the list in order to have just `List<Animal>`, then map into a list of `name`s and finally `collect` them into the result.

```
return caretakers.stream()
    .filter(caretaker -> caretaker.getNumber() == caretakerID)
    .map(caretaker -> caretaker.getAnimals())
    .flatMap(animals -> animals.stream())
    .map(animal -> animal.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `findFirst` for finding a *"specific caretaker"* and return the list of animals as you perform a `map`ping operation in order to *"return the names of the animals he/she takes care"*.

```
return caretakers.stream()
                 .filter(caretaker -> caretaker.getNumber() == caretakerID)
                 .findFirst()
                 .map(x -> x.getDieren().stream() // this conversion was missing
                        .map(Animal::getNaam)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                 .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Remember, `forEach` is a `void` operation and does not return a result from its execution.

Comment: Is there no need to collect it after mapping?

Comment: @DennisB. It's based on the statement *return the names of the animals he/she takes care*. Further, the `map` is on an `Optional` and not `Stream` here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the animal names only, this should help:

```
List<String> animals = caretakers.stream()
                                 .filter(c -> c.getNumber() = caretakerID)
                                 .map(Caretaker::getAnimals)
                                 .map(Collection::stream)
                                 .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
                                 .map(Animal::getName)
                                 .collect(toList());
```

Another approach:

```
List<Animal> animals = caretakers.stream()
                                  .filter(c -> c.getNummer() = caretakerID)
                                  .findFirst()
                                  .map(Caretaker::getAnimals)
                                  .orElse(emptyList());

List<String> names = animals.stream()
                            .map(Animal::getName)
                            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: `flatMap`ping would need a `stream()`, one can use `.flatMap(careTaker -> careTaker.getAnimals().stream().map(Animal::getName))` as well.

Comment: @Naman Right, it's `Optional::flatMap`, not `Stream::flatMap`. Updated the answer.